# C# Listview text importing function does nothing

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, streamreader

i am trying to import .txt file contents to my listview, the text file is already saved as multiple lines in this structure: "Line ID"＾"String"
i use this code to import the data:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text file";
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName, Encoding.UTF8);
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string[] a2 = sr.ReadLine().Split('＾');
            if (a2.Length == 3)
            {
                int aa = int.Parse(a2[0].ToString());

                textView.Items[aa].SubItems[1].Text = a2[1];
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
```

it loads the OFD, select the txt file, then nothing, it gives no exception/error whatsoever, it just does nothing, is there something wrong with my code ?

Comment: Put a break point and make sure it falls in the while loop.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your code.  You use a2 before it's declared; I expect it should be a1.Length == 3.

Comment: You are using string[] a1 as array, but later you refer to a2, which hasn't been declared/initiated. Looks like a bug.

Comment: im new to break points so sorry in advance, i put a break point on the while line, when i clicked on the import and chosen the file, it just gave me a Yellow arrow on the red BP circle, what should i do if you may ? also corrected the code but still same result

Comment: Can you post an actual example of a couple of lines of the text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the line, and then testing if the resulting array has 3 elements, in the line

```
if (a2.Length == 3)
```

If each line really has only 2 parts - LineId and string, then you should be testing for 2 array elements:

```
if (a2.Length == 2)
```

The code appears to do nothing because the If evaluates to false based on your data.

Also, the line:

```
textView.Items[aa].SubItems[1].Text = a2[1];
```

Relies on the Item with index aa already being created. you should create the items and add them to the list view first.

Comment: the import is actually a replacement, it replaces already existing data, and it also gives me an out of range exception on that line "textView.Items[aa].Subitems[1].Text = a2[1])

Comment: tried it same result, i think that the out of range is for the items[aa], i fixed it, i just ahd to put aa - 1